# Select after joining three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've just joined 3 tables (picture in link).

Is there anyway for select all of the recept_navn, where the "raavare_navn" is NOT "champignon"? [Here][1] is my code.

```
SELECT RECEPT.RECEPT_ID, RECEPT.RECEPT_NAVN, RAAVARE.RAAVARE_NAVN 
FROM RECEPT 
INNER JOIN RECEPTKOMPONENT ON RECEPT.RECEPT_ID = RECEPTKOMPONENT.RECEPT_ID 
INNER JOIN RAAVARE ON RAAVARE.RAAVARE_ID = RECEPTKOMPONENT.RAAVARE_ID
```

[1]:

https://scontent.fcph1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/18302492_10211642606955497_1361966660_n.png?oh=39fbf75c8be2bfd5abae35803c7d176a&oe=590E71F3

Comment: Dont provide link for the code... try to giv that code here

Comment: Okay, sorry. Im kind of new to all this stackoverflow. But anyway

SELECT RECEPT.RECEPT_ID, RECEPT.RECEPT_NAVN, RAAVARE.RAAVARE_NAVN
FROM RECEPT INNER JOIN RECEPTKOMPONENT
ON RECEPT.RECEPT_ID = RECEPTKOMPONENT.RECEPT_ID
INNER JOIN RAAVARE
ON RAAVARE.RAAVARE_ID = RECEPTKOMPONENT.RAAVARE_ID

Comment: You want a simple exclusion join, but see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query if you're still struggling.

Comment: For more discussion on this subject, you might look at https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,507748,507839#msg-507839

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use where

```
SELECT RECEPT.RECEPT_ID, RECEPT.RECEPT_NAVN, RAAVARE.RAAVARE_NAVN 
FROM RECEPT 
INNER JOIN RECEPTKOMPONENT ON RECEPT.RECEPT_ID = RECEPTKOMPONENT.RECEPT_ID 
INNER JOIN RAAVARE ON RAAVARE.RAAVARE_ID = RECEPTKOMPONENT.RAAVARE_ID 
where 

        RAAVARE.RAAVARE_NAVN 

                             <> "champignon"
```

if you need  the margherita and prosciutto you could use

```
  SELECT RECEPT.RECEPT_ID, RECEPT.RECEPT_NAVN, RAAVARE.RAAVARE_NAVN 
  FROM RECEPT 
  INNER JOIN RECEPTKOMPONENT ON RECEPT.RECEPT_ID = RECEPTKOMPONENT.RECEPT_ID 
  INNER JOIN RAAVARE ON RAAVARE.RAAVARE_ID = RECEPTKOMPONENT.RAAVARE_ID 
  where RECEPT.RECEPT_ID not in ( 

      SELECT RECEPT.RECEPT_ID
      FROM RECEPT 
      INNER JOIN RECEPTKOMPONENT ON RECEPT.RECEPT_ID = RECEPTKOMPONENT.RECEPT_ID 
      INNER JOIN RAAVARE ON RAAVARE.RAAVARE_ID = RECEPTKOMPONENT.RAAVARE_ID 
      where RAAVARE.RAAVARE_NAVN = "champignon"
    )
```

Comment: It is possible to write "not"? I did not know that, thank you very much!

Comment: ops   .  a mistake   ..anyway answer  updated .. is not  is <>  in sql

Comment: @Suicidalllama I'm surprised. I imagined that you simply wanted 'margherita' and 'prosciutto'. Either way, I now need pizza.

Comment: It should print out Margherita and Prosciutto, however the darn thing is still printing out Capricciosa. :(

Comment: @Suicidalllama answer updated  for Margherita and Prosciutto

Comment: `RECEPTKOMPONENT.RAAVARE_ID  = "champignon" ` !! ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry  thanks .. wrongs table and column name  .. answer  udpated

Comment: Well, it's getting warmer.

Comment: We especially hope the pizzas are good. With the slim dough and abundant ingredients